# PIP on Python 3.12 Macos Sonoma

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I'm trying to run Python 3.12 on Macos Sonoma and I'm finding difficulties with pip.
I'm running the line to install it like bellow

```
Last login: Thu Mar 28 10:22:29 on ttys000
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Python 3.12 % sudo easy_install pip
Password:
sudo: easy_install: command not found
```

Any alternative?

Comment: `pip` is bunled with the standard python installation. Use `python -m pip --version` to check you have it

Comment: You didn't show us how you reached the conclusion that you don't have pip already (as above: you should), or how you reached the conclusion that you should have easy_install already.

Comment: isn't it enough to just type:
pip install package_name? As long as you have pip, I think you don't need easy_install.
easy_install is deprecated, isn't it?